# fastest way to find position of a number in an uneven array with known delta function

Tags: python

Let us say I divide the x-axis as follows:

```
def linear_delta(x):
    return 10*(-2.39916666666673e-06*x+0.014588678333333336)

current = 26.0
my_array = [current]
while current < 50.1:
    current+=linear_delta(current)
    my_array.append(current)
```

With linear_delta being a linear function that changes linearly as we move along the x-axis.

I.e.,

the x-axis starts at `26.0`, then next breakpoint is at

```
26.0+d1=26.1446, where d1=linear_delta(26.0) etc.
```

And the general division of the x-axis looks like:

```
|--------|-------|------|-----|----|
s   d1      d2      d3     d4   d5 e
```

where, `s`: start position (`26.0` in our example); `e`: end position in our example (`50.21067768889078` in our example).

Now, given a position in the x-axis, let us say `x`.  How can I know which position in the x-axis this `x` follows into?

In the case of an evenly spaced axis it would be `math.floor((x-start)/len)`, with `len=e-s`.

Is there a similar simple and fast formula for this uneven case with a linear delta function?

Comment: What is `linear_delta`? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnColeman absolutely, I forgot to put the function there, my mistake

Comment: If the linear delta function is known when you write your code, you could mathematically invert and could also integrate the cumulative deltas. Basically, you're finding the x coordinate on a parabola given a y-value. This should be achievable in constant time if you know the linear delta function ahead of time. Even if you don't know the linear delta function ahead of time, you could write code that figures out what the delta=a*x+b coefficients are and transform that into `x = a*idx^2+b*idx+c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best viewed as one of iterating a linear function. Note that if you have code like `x += g(x)` where `g(x) = k*x+b` then this is equivalent to `x = f(x)` where `m = k+1`. In your case, `m = 1 + 10*-2.39916666666673e-06` which is `0.9999760083333333`

If you are iterating `f(x) = m*x+b` starting with a seed value `x_0`, by taking the partial sum of a geometric series you can work out that after `k` iterations you have the value

```
m^k*x_0 + b*(m^k-1)/(m-1)
```

To find the largest `k` where this expression is <= a given x, first solve for `m^k`:

```
m^k <= (x+b/(m-1))/(x_0 + b/(m-1))
```

Thus

```
  k ?? math.log((x+b/(m-1))/(x_0 + b/(m-1)),m)
```

Where `??` is either `<=` or `>=` depending on if `m < 1` or `m>1`. In your case, `m < 1` hence `??` is `>=` and you would need to take the floor.

For example:

```
from math import log, floor

x_0 = 26.0
m = 1+ 10*-2.39916666666673e-06
b = 10*0.014588678333333336

def index(x):
    return floor(log((x+b/(m-1))/(x_0 + b/(m-1)),m))
```

Test:

```
>>> index(35)
62
>>> my_array[62:64]
[34.99971883425056, 35.144765915996196]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since StackOverflow doesn't support MathTeX, you get a crude markdown version instead.

Your series is a recurrence relation:

```
x1 = x0 + linear_delta(x0)
x2 = x1 + linear_delta(x1)
x3 = ...
```

And `linear_delta has the form:

```
linear_delta(x) = m*x + b
```

Steps to get the recurrence relation into simplified form:

```
x1 = x0 + linear_delta(x0)
   = x0 + m*x0 + b    
   = (m+1)*x0 + b
         let n=m+1
   = n*x0 + b

x2 = n*x1 + b = n*(n*x0 + b) + b
   = n²*x0 + n*b + b

x3 = n*x2 + b
   = n*(n²*x0 + n*b + b) + b
   = n³*x0 + n²*b + n*b + b

xk = n^k*x0 + b*sum(n^h, h=0..k-1)
```

If we can solve the summation for an explicit function of `n` and `k`, then we have an explicit formula for `x`. Invert that formula and we can find the index for a given `x`.

Following the recurrence relation solving instructions from https://www.wikihow.com/Solve-Recurrence-Relations
Let's adapt their example:

> 2, 5, 14, 41, 122
>
> a_n = 3 * a_(n-1) - 1

Using our recurrence relation:

a_n = (m+1) * a_(n-1) + b

```
A(x) = sum(a_k * x^k, k=0..∞)
     = a0 + sum(a_k * x^k, k=1..∞)
     = a0 + sum(((m+1) * a_(k-1) + b) * x^k, k=1..∞)
     = a0 + sum((m+1) * a_(k-1) * x^k, k=1..∞) + sum(b * x^k, k=1..∞)
     = a0 + (m+1)*x*sum(a_(k-1) * x^(k-1), k=1..∞) + b*sum(x^k, k=1..∞)
A(x) = a0 + (m+1)*x*A(x) + b*x/(1-x)

(1 - (m+1)*x)*A(x) = a0 + b*x/(1-x)
A(x) = (a0 + b*x/(1-x)) / (1 - (m+1)*x)
A(x) =   a0*(1-x) + b*x
       -------------------
       (x-1)*((m+1)*x - 1)
```

And continue solving per the instructions